# Android: how to get rid of scrollView's "fading edge"

Tags: android, scrollbar

I'm having a problem with a text view embedded in a ScrollView. That is, when I scroll the text a thin orange line briefly appears to show that I've gone as far as a can in a particular direction. I've tried a couple of things like "android:fadingEdge="none" and setting the background color, but it's just staying there.

How do I get rid of or control these "end of scroll" colors?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

What you're seeing isn't the "fading edge" normally shown while you're scrolled into content, it's the "over-scroll" effect in Gingerbread and newer. From your XML you can set `android:overScrollMode` to "always", "never", or "ifContentScrolls".

"always" and "never" should be self-explanatory, "ifContentScrolls" will only show the effect if the content does not fully fit within the view without scrolling.

Comment: Yeah, ignore my answer -- I misread what the question was about.  Overscroll is correct.  You can also set it in code with [View#setOverScrollMode()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOverScrollMode(int))

Comment: That answers another question I had, which was how to indicate a scroll was available. Also what it was I was looking at. However, I still can't seem to change that orange color...

Comment: No, there is currently no public API to change the effect.

Comment: Ideally it can be done, somehow i tried for scrollview and the darn thing did not work. However, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889908/android-scrollview-fading-edge you can completely hide it be making it return 0.0F always.