# How to make Android ScrollView fading edge always visible?

Tags: android, scrollview, fading

By default scrollview's fading edge is visible only if it is possible to scroll in that direction. How can I make it visible at all times?

I don't want to put any drawables on top or something like that. I want to accomplish it using the builtin fading edge, probably by overriding some scrollview functions.

Comment: Can you please tell, why would you want to do that? The fading effect is designed for the specific purpose of informing the user that he can scroll in that direction. If you change it to always show fading edge, the user would think he can scroll in any direction and think that something is broken when it isn't possible.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, extend ScrollView and override these methods (based on Donut-release2):

```
@Override
protected float getTopFadingEdgeStrength() {
    if (getChildCount() == 0) {
        return 0.0f;
    }
    return 1.0f;
}

@Override
protected float getBottomFadingEdgeStrength() {
    if (getChildCount() == 0) {
        return 0.0f;
    }
    return 1.0f;
}
```

For comparison's sake, this is the original code, which shortens the fading edge as you get close to the end of the list:

```
@Override
protected float getTopFadingEdgeStrength() {
    if (getChildCount() == 0) {
        return 0.0f;
    }

    final int length = getVerticalFadingEdgeLength();
    if (mScrollY < length) {
        return mScrollY / (float) length;
    }

    return 1.0f;
}

@Override
protected float getBottomFadingEdgeStrength() {
    if (getChildCount() == 0) {
        return 0.0f;
    }

    final int length = getVerticalFadingEdgeLength();
    final int bottomEdge = getHeight() - mPaddingBottom;
    final int span = getChildAt(0).getBottom() - mScrollY - bottomEdge;
    if (span < length) {
        return span / (float) length;
    }

    return 1.0f;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following code:

```
public class TopFadeEdgeScrollView extends ScrollView {

public TopFadeEdgeScrollView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public TopFadeEdgeScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public TopFadeEdgeScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
protected float getBottomFadingEdgeStrength() {
    return 0.0f;
}
}
```